# How to combine arrays based on identical words in different cases?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm going through [the Python NLTK book](http://nltk.org/book). I made a frequency distribution of the words in Moby Dick by running: `fdist=FreqDist(text1)` where text1 is an NLTK Text object for Moby Dick, i.e. a list of the words in the novel. Now I have a frequency distribution object:

```
>>> fdist1
<FreqDist with 260819 outcomes>
```

Yet many of those in the list are the same words in different cases, like the word "a" in both uppercase and lowercase:

```
>>> fdist1['a']
4569
>>> fdist1['A']
167
```

How can I combine these two words (and every other word listed separately)?

Comment: Why can't you just lowercase everything before adding it to your frequency distribution? I presume capitalization doesn't matter in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dict, iterate over the FreqDict and lowercase the key. Like so -

```
lc_dict = defaultdict(int)
for (key, value) in fdist1.items():
    lc_dict[key.lower()] = lc_dict[key.lower()] + value
```